# How to fit a standardized generalized hyperbolic distribution to my data using optim?

Tags: r, optimization, fitting, standardization

I want to fit a standardized generalized hyperbolid distribution to my data using the optim command.

Regarding my post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58547/r-command-to-fit-a-standardized-generalized-hyperbolic-distribution-to-data), I think I have to try it manually, by using the optim command.
My problem is, that the optimization command leads to parameter values, which are not defined, so I get the error message:

```
Fehler in if (delta <= 0) stop("delta must be greater than zero")
```

See the following code (my data can be found here):

```
library(fBasics)
startvalue<-c(1,0,1)
loglikstandghyp <-function(zetapar,rhopar,lambdapar){
if(par>0) return(-sum(log(dsgh(mydata,zeta=zetapar,rho=rhopar,lambda=lambdapar))))
else return(Inf)
}

#shape parameter zeta is positive, skewness parameter rho is in the range (-1, 1). 
optim(startvalue, fn=loglikstandghyp, method="BFGS")
param = optim(startvalue,loglikstandghyp, method="BFGS")$par
```

This leads to the result, that optim sets the parameters to a value, which are not allowed. So my question is, how can I to this correctly?

[R says](http://help.rmetrics.org/fBasics/dist-sgh.html): shape parameter zeta is positive, skewness parameter rho is in the range (-1, 1).

I cannot use Brent-method to give the range allowed for the parameters, because Brent is only for one-dimensional problems.

So the problem is to use the optim command, but I have to give some restrictions, how can I do this?

Afterwards, I would use the .paramGH(zeta,rho,lambda) command to change the parametrization into the desired alpha, beta, delta, mu, lambda parametrization.

Do you think what I am doing is correct?

EDIT: Even if I use other starting values and the L-BFGS-B method like in the following, I still get the error message:

```
startvalue<-c(20,0,1)
optim(startvalue, fn=loglikstandghyp, method="L-
BFGS-B",lower=c(0.00000001,-1,-Inf),upper=c(Inf,1,Inf))
```

EDIT: Ok, I now tried the following:

```
optim(startvalue, fn=loglikstandghyp, method="L-
BFGS-B",lower=c(0.00000001,-0.999999999,-Inf),upper=c(Inf,0.99999999,Inf))
```

This seems to be better, but my problem now is, that the solution is highly dependent on the startingvalues and I don't know, what starting values are appropriate?

E.g. If I set the starting values to `startvalue<-c(100,-0.5,90)` I get:

```
> optim(startvalue, fn=loglikstandghyp, method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.00000001,-0.999999999,-Inf),upper=c(Inf,0.99999999,Inf))
$par
[1] 100.0189990   0.3125539  90.0142759
```

And If I set them to `startvalue<-c(50,0.5,1)`:

```
> optim(startvalue, fn=loglikstandghyp, method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.00000001,-0.999999999,-Inf),upper=c(Inf,0.99999999,Inf))
$par
[1] 0.00000001 0.09105067 8.27463528
```

Totally different, so what should I do?

Comment: I have also found this problem with NIG distribution. I am wondering if you have solved this problem?

Comment: @newhotter First of all: No, I did not solve the problem. But I think I found the reason for it: In my case the change in the log-likelihood is only around the third digit after decimal mark. So the change in the log-likelihood due to a change in the parameters is very small. This means, the log-likelihood must be extreme flat. I don't know what people do in such a case.